# How to add list items outside form in hidden field

Tags: javascript, php, csv, listbox

I have 2 lists - master and category. When moving items from master list to category list I can save category list with new values but unable to save master list with removed items. I was thinking of means of reading master list into hidden field of category list but not sure how to go about. Need help with this and herewith my code:-

```
<select name=master[] id=master class="master" multiple="multiple" size='6'>
<?php   
    $file = fopen("master.csv", "r");
    while (($row = fgetcsv($file, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $master = $row[0];
?>
    <option value="<?php echo $master;?>"><?php echo $master; ?></option>
<?php
    }
?>
</select> 

<form action="" method="post">
    <input type=button class="master" name=b1 id=b1 value='Move >'>
    <input type=button class="master" name=b2 id=b2 value='< Remove'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<select name=category[] id=category multiple="multiple" class=master>
<?php   
    $file = fopen("category.csv", "r");
    while (($row = fgetcsv($file, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $category = $row[0];
?>
    <option value="<?php echo $category;?>"><?php echo $category;?></option>
<?php
    }
?>
</select>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="submit" value="Save File" name="submit">
</form>
```

The move and remove function works so I am not including it but here is my js for writing to csv file.

```
<?php

if ($_POST['master']) {
$master = $_POST['master'];
foreach ($master as $key => $value) {
    $result.=$value. "\n";
}
file_put_contents('master.csv',$result);
}

if ($_POST['category']) {
$category = $_POST['category'];
$categoryunique = array_unique($category);
sort($categoryunique);
foreach ($categoryunique as $key => $value) {
    $result.=$value. "\n";
}
file_put_contents('category.csv',$result);
}
?>
```

Comment: why cant you move the master select inside form?

Comment: There is 68 different categories which is related to 1 master listbox

Comment: take a look at  [this](http://loudev.com/) , i think if you move master in form tag, it will send post with master values, or if you are using JS, then use event on submit, and attack master with post,

Comment: Thanx will have a look at it